# Boostrap columns in row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I don't understand how to do this thing in bootstrap 
Situation as in image

[image: image-boostrap]

I have a row with a backgroung-image-->then the columns : col-sm-2 / col-sm-5 / col-sm-5 with other elements !
ok !
I want to insert a button (in center)
how Can I do ??

thanks !

Comment: Please make an edit to include the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following in your template...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        Column #1
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
        Column #2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        Column #3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
         <button>Centered Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

or add a parent element that contains two rows and put your background image on that element.

```
<div class="elem-with-bg">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            Column #1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            Column #2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            Column #3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <button>Centered Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```